# Proving a function is integrable over $[0,1]$

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

I have been given the following problem:

> Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[0,1]$. Suppose that $f$ is integrable on each closed interval $[a,b]$ of $(0,1)$. Prove that $f$ is intergrable on $[0,1]$.

Now, I was thinking of starting by defining $E=[0,1-\varepsilon]$, which would mean that $f$ is integrable over $E$. But I am not really sure where to go with this idea. Some guidance would be great!

Comment: For starters, do you know of any criteria involving upper and lower sums that guarantee Riemann integrability?

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows that $ f $ is Darboux integrable.

It suffices to show that for each $ \epsilon > 0$, there is a partition P of $ [0, 1] $ such that the upper and the lower Riemann sums (denoted by $ S(P) $ and $ s(P) $) differ by $ \epsilon $ at most.

Following your idea, since $ f $ is integrable on $ [0, 1 - \delta] $ for any $ 0 < \delta \leq 1 $, there is a partition $ Q $ of this interval such that $ S(Q) - s(Q) < \delta/2 $. Then, $ P = Q \cup \{1\} $ is the desired partition for an appropriate choice of $ \delta $, as we have that

$$ S(P) - s(P) = S(Q) + \delta \sup_{x\in [1 - \delta, 1]} f(x) - s(Q) - \delta \inf_{x\in [1 - \delta, 1]} f(x) $$

and now $ f $ is bounded, so that we have $ m \leq f(x) \leq M $ in the interval for some constants $ m, M $ and

$$ < \frac{\delta}{2} + (M - m) \delta = \frac{1 + 2M - 2m}{2} \delta$$

and picking $ \delta = 2\epsilon/(1 + 2M - 2m) $ gives that $ S(P) - s(P) < \epsilon $.

Comment: Is Darboux the same as Riemann integrable ?

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent, in that a function is Darboux integrable iff it is Riemann integrable, and in that case the values of the integrals agree.

Comment: But are the definitions the same ?

Comment: No, they are not, although they can be shown to be equivalent, as I said above.

The OP does not make it clear which definition of the integral we are to work with, and which results we may assume to be true about that integral, so I proved the result for one definition.

Comment: Are you learning mathematics from Wikipedia ?

Comment: Not sure why you would ask that question... would you like to clarify?

Comment: Do you not want to answer it ?